# No overload for method 'GETValues' takes 0 arguments

Tags: parameters, overloading

I needed to return three values of two variable types, so I decided to use the *ref* and *out* params, but I'm having trouble implementing them. I keep getting these "No overload for method 'GETValues' takes 0 arguments" errors. What am I doing wrong?

```
public static double GETValues(out string empName, out double dblSal, out double dblMonthSales)
    {
        string salaryStr,
               monthlySales;

        Console.Write("Enter employee's name (enter nothing to quit) : ");
        empName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter Annual Salary (0 for pure commission): ");
        salaryStr = Console.ReadLine();
        dblMonthSales = Double.Parse(salaryStr);
        Console.Write("Enter monthly sales: ");
        monthlySales = Console.ReadLine();
        dblSal = Double.Parse(monthlySales);

        return dblMonthSales;
        return dblSal;
```

Comment: Looks like your calling code isn't passing the variables in - but since you haven't posted it we can't be sure... Your terminology is "odd" this won't return 3 values, it will populate 3 values passed in and return 1 double.

Comment: Ok, let me add the rest of the code...

Answer (score 0):

You don't do multiple returns. You set the values of the out variables (which you already do).
You can return one double - but in your snippet you are trying to return two values which you have already set in "out" parameters.

Your calling code should be something like:

```
string empname = "default";
double salary = 0.0;
double monthSales = 0.0;
double whatIsThis = GETValues(empname, salary, monthsales);
// empname, salary and monthSales should now be set correctly.
// not sure what you intend for the return val.
```